# What counts as a surrounded perimeter in Ireland?

Tags: ireland, public-health

According to the [2004 amendment](https://www.tobaccocontrollaws.org/files/live/Ireland/Ireland%20-%20PHA%202004%20-%20national.pdf) to the 2002 Public Health (Tobacco) Act, which I believe is still legally binding, smoking tobacco is prohibited except in certain conditions. Among them are the following:

> (7) This section shall not apply to—
>
> (a) a dwelling,
>
> (b) a prison,
>
> (c) subject to paragraph (d), a place or premises, or a part of a
> place or premises, that is wholly uncovered by any roof, whether fixed
> or movable,
>
> (d) an outdoor part of a place or premises covered by a fixed or
> movable roof, provided that not more than 50 per cent of the perimeter
> of that part is surrounded by one or more walls or similar structures
> (inclusive of windows, doors, gates or other means of access to or
> egress from that part),

It is that last portion that I am curious about. In standard mathematical usage, the [perimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perimeter) of a zone is its linear bound.

- So, for instance, under this interpretation, if one side of the space is the entrance to my establishment, and I put a two-foot wall (say) on two of the other three sides, then it is illegal to smoke tobacco in that region?
- Contrariwise, perhaps the law is based on surface area instead. If I put up three walls, each of which covers 51% of the region between itself and the roof, is it illegal to smoke tobacco in that region?
- Is there some other criterion for the minimum amount a wall must surround on this perimeter? For instance, perhaps a 45% height wall is not considered a wall at all, and so if I have a 90% height wall, and two 49% height walls, in addition to the wall that contains the entrance, smoking can be permitted, even though there are walls on three sides and more than 50% of the total area is covered. If a wall has to go from floor to ceiling, I can easily create a smoking space that is walled in putting in a 6-inch gap, say.
- For that matter, is the wall (presumably with an entrance) between the outdoor part and my establishment included in the perimeter, under any of those interpretations?

Which of these meanings, or any other, is at play in Ireland's laws regarding public smoking?

Answer (score 1):

The word "perimeter" must be read in line with the [Interpretation Act 2005, Section 5(1)](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/2005/act/23/section/5/enacted/en/html#sec5) if there is any doubt about the meaning of the word:

> 5.—(1) In construing a provision of any Act (other than a provision that relates to the imposition of a penal or other sanction)—
>
> (a) that is obscure or ambiguous, or
>
> (b) that on a literal interpretation would be absurd or would fail to reflect the plain intention of—
>
> (i) in the case of an Act to which paragraph (a) of the definition of “Act” in section 2 (1) relates, the Oireachtas, or
>
> (ii) in the case of an Act to which paragraph (b) of that definition relates, the parliament concerned,
>
> the provision shall be given a construction that reflects the plain intention of the Oireachtas or parliament concerned, as the case may be, where that intention can be ascertained from the Act as a whole.

In this case, the word "perimeter" would likely be given its ordinary, plain, every-day meaning. That is not the same as the "standard mathematical usage" of the word.

Comment: Is the Interpretation Act *ex post facto*?

Comment: @Obie2.0 Yes, it is. See [Part 1 of the Act](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/2005/act/23/enacted/en/print#sec2) where it effectively applies to _any_ Act made prior, at the same time, or after this Act.

Answer (score 0):

### A wall is a wall no matter how tall or open it is

That’s what the “inclusive of windows, doors, gates or other means of access to or egress from that part” means.

So a full solid wall can only be on 50% of the sides. As can a 3 foot high wall. Or an awning that comes down 2 foot from the roof.

At least 50% of the perimeter must be completely open from the ground to the roof.

Comment: Possible, certainly. But is this reading confirmed by any future law, common law, or general practice in the Republic? Also, this answer does not address whether the fourth wall - that between the space and the indoors - counts as part of the perimeter of the space.

Comment: @Obie2.0 that fourth wall that is clearly a wall? Yes, laws about walls apply to walls.

Comment: The question is whether that might not count as the perimeter of the *outdoor part*, being part of the perimeter of the indoor part. Again, your interpretation seems most reasonable to me, but it is not clear that this is either the definition that the law uses, nor how it is applied.

Comment: @Obie2.0 are you asking if the wall that separates the outside from the inside is on the perimeter of the outside? Or if that whole side is somehow not on the edge of the outside?

Comment: Precisely. Also, your interpretation of "inclusive of windows, doors" et cetera is that it implies that the height of the wall is irrelevant, but it could easily be read as being intended to rule out someone saying that a wall is not a wall because it contains a door. Typically, an air space above a wall is not considered a "means of access or egress."

Comment: That's why I am more interested in an answer that cites any case law or clarifying statutes that may have been developed in the last 16 years. In terms of an interpretation, well, everyone has one. I agree with yours, basically, but I am not the competent legal authority.